# ArrowKT - @optics annotation not generating code

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

How do you setup the Arrow dependencies for `@optics` annotation to actually work? No companion objects are generated for the data classes annotated with `@optics`.

If I'm not mistaken, this is an annotation processor, so it should be imported using `kapt`, however [the documentation](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/quickstart/libraries/index.html#arrow-optics) uses it as `compile`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For arrow 0.10.0

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

def arrow_version = "0.10.1-SNAPSHOT"
dependencies {
    implementation "io.arrow-kt:arrow-optics:$arrow_version"
    implementation "io.arrow-kt:arrow-syntax:$arrow_version"
    kapt    "io.arrow-kt:arrow-meta:$arrow_version" // <-- this is the kapt plugin
}
```

then:

```
@optics data class Street(val number: Int, val name: String) {
    companion object {} // <-- this is required
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can see the generated classes. However I can't access the Optics DSL as explained [here](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/optics/dsl/). Am I missing more dependencies?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're not accessing?

Comment: Forget it, I just had to add the generated source code to the source set as explained [here](https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/generating-code-via-annotations-in-kotlin).

Answer (score 1):

Everything is explained in the documentation, I don't know how I missed it

https://arrow-kt.io/docs/